# Как запретить удаление первых символов в input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть поле ввода (input), в котором через JavaScript автоматом прописывается начальное значение из трех символов. С помощью такого скрипта я запрещаю удаления этих трех символов:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8 && $('#input-new').is(':focus') && $('#input-new').val().length < 4) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Но если написать в поле ввода минимум четвертый символ, а после нажать *Ctrl+A*, или иначе выбрать весь текст, или переместить курсор к началу и нажать *Backspace*, то удаление сработает.

---

Как можно полностью запретить удаление первых трех символов?

Comment: мжб просто сделать поверх какой-нибудь спан слева с этими символами, а человек пусть вводит все что хочет и скрипта не надо.

Comment: @Skywave, это будет самый простой, контролируемый и с предсказуемым для пользователя поведением вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно никого никуда не запрещать) А при отправке - собрать числа из двух элементов.

```css
#first, #last {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: blorder-box;
  display: inline;
  outline: none;
}
#first {  
  border-right: none;
}
#last {  
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="first" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.focus();">+8 123</span><input id="last">
```

Касаемо скрипта, если полноценно отслеживать backspace - в теории можно выделить всё и CTRL + V. Никто так делать не будет, но всё же... можно дать нормально вводить числа, а после каждого ввода первые 4 символа заменять на нужные:

```js
// $('#bubu').on('input', function(){...});

document.getElementById('bubu').addEventListener('input', function(){
  this.value = "+123" + this.value.slice(4);
});
```

```css
#bubu { font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<input id="bubu" value="+123">
```

Comment: Просто красавчик Вы, второй вариант то что нужно!

Answer (score 3):

Вариант без скрипта.

Поверх ввода располагаем span с текстом, который не должен удаляться.

```css
.control {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  padding-left: 23px;
}

.prefix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="prefix">bla</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#input-new').on("keydown", function(e) {
    // Запрет выделения ctrl + a
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 65) return false;

  // Запрет выделения клавишами
  if (e.shiftKey && ((e.keyCode === 37 && this.selectionStart < 4) || (e.keyCode === 39 && this.selectionStart < 3)
  || e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40)) 
  return false;

  // Запрет удаления через backspace и del
  if (e.keyCode == 46 && this.selectionStart < 3)
    return false;
  else if (e.keyCode == 8 && this.selectionStart < 4)
    return false;
});
```

Попробуйте этот вариант. Вместо того, чтобы вешать глобальное событие я повесил событие на конкретное поле, в данном случае на #input-new. Решение правда может не работать в старых браузерах. Но вроде как код запрещает удаление первых 3х символов даже если переместим курсор куда угодно. Добавил еще обработку клавиши *DEL* так как ей тоже можем удалять текст. Так же запретил выделение через клавиши. Мышкой правда все равно можно выделять и проблема остается. Можно конечно попробовать запретить выделять текст вообще и тогда проблема решится. Правда решение будет длиннее и возможно работать с таким полем будет не совсем удобно.